# Does açaí provide special benefits against diabetes?

Tags: natural-remedies, diabetes

The fruit "açaí" is marketed in the US as having special antioxidant-related nutritional value. A frequently heard claim is that is provides special benefits against diabetes.

The price of any product containing this berry makes me very suspicious. Other reasons for a skeptic attitude include its marketing with an exotic orthography (not just Anglicized "acai") and the fact that it is virtually never sold by itself but only ever with other fruits providing flavors. This makes it very hard to verify any claim about just açaí in particular (because any effect from any product could also come from other ingredients).

Is this a scam?

Comment: @sklivvz: If you are going to change the question and then change my answer, at least do it with some editorial grace. Yeah, this is very meta, but that was imperious, so it evens out.